# Building and refresh static list

Tags: c#

How can I build key pair list ( int? Key, string Value) and refresh it after I get new xml:

```
        List<KvPair> source = new List<KvPair>
        {
            new KvPair {Key = null, Value = "Null"},
            new KvPair {Key = 0, Value = "No"},
            new KvPair {Key = 1, Value = "Yes"}

        };
```

List depends from xml. If I will refresh list and will get only 2 values from xml : null, 0 then list should have only 2 elements:

```
    new KvPair {Key = null, Value = "Null"},
    new KvPair {Key = 1, Value = "Yes"}
```

Should I use static list?
Is better way than that:

```
 private List<KvPair> RebuildList(object extendData)  //extendedData  is xml
  {
    List<KvPair> source = new List<KvPair>
    {
       new KvPair {Key = null, Value = "Null"},
       new KvPair {Key = 0, Value = "No"},
       new KvPair {Key = 1, Value = "Yes"}      
    };
    List<int> target = new List<int>();
    var data = XDocument.Parse(extendData.ToString()).Descendants("elem");
    int tempVal;

    foreach (var elem in data)
    {
      var key = Int32.TryParse(elem.Attribute("Value").Value,
             out tempVal) ? tempVal : null;
      target.Add(key)
    }
   source.RemoveAll(x => !target.Contains(x));

   return new List<KvPair>(source);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better implement your own class which will work with List below but you will implement your own Add method and there you will refresh your List as you want before the adding.